# Expected hash. myObject.id evaluated instead to freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel

Tags: freemarker

I have searched Google, read the docs etc, but I can still not figure out what is going wrong.

When I try to access a nested property, say `${myObject.id.str}` of an object I get the following error: `Expected hash. myObject.id evaluated instead to freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel`. When I remove the `.str` and simply attempt to output `${myObject.id}` I get `Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression myObject.id is instead a freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel`. Id is actually an object - it is a wrapper of `java.lang.Number`. I simply added the `str()` method as a convenient way of getting the number value because I thought that returning a string might help. This does not appear to be a problem however as the problem seems to be the Id-object itself. I am beginning to wonder whether I have got a naming issue because calling `myobject.myId` seems to work but not `myobject.id`. Coud this be true because the class-name `Id` is identical to the propety name `id`? I shouldn't think so normally, but why would `myId` work which has the same `Id` object.

The Object looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private Id id = null;

    @Override
    public Id getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Id id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    } 
}
```

The id class looks as follows:

```
public class Id extends Number
{
    private Number id = null;

    public String getStr()
    {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
}
```

The following does not work in the template:

```
${myObject.id}
```

The Freemarker documentation is good as long as you don't run into any problems. Unfortunately after reading the docs over and over again and googling I am still not getting any closer to a solution.

It would be excellent if anyone could shed a light on this.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Just for a test I added another method called "public Id getIdStr()" which is just a copy of getId() and that works, even without explicitly turning it into a string. Surely the solution cannot be to rename all my getId() methods to something else ... that would affect quite a lot of code :-(.

Comment: I have now found out that ${myObject.getId()} also works, but I am not really happy with that because I want to be able to use the normal expression ${myObject.id}. I just do not understand what freemarker is doing here ... looks like as if I will have to dig deeper ... it would nice of course if someone else has had a similar experience and knows what I am doing wrong ...

Comment: I hope this helps someone else one day ... I have now added an Id field (private Id id = null;) and an appropriate getter method directly to my action bean. I then attempt to get the value in the template with the line "${actionBean.id}" and that works! Weird, I keep on finding other ways where it does work but the actual code in question still causes an error.

Comment: I sounds like if your object had an `id` method (in Java), which thus shadows the JavaBean property of the same name. Isn't that the case?

Comment: BTW why do you need getStr()?

Comment: Hi, I don't actually need it - it was a desperate attempt to get something working. Thanks for the tip, I actually checked that because I have had that error before - thankfully after spending some time searching for that error, I found out what was going on. So unforunately there is no id() method which could be causing this. I have made 2 further tests now which might give a hint. I have now added that whole nested object structure to my actionBean and ${actionBean.testObject.id} works (also if it is a list of testObjects) ...

Comment: My comment was too long:

One other reason could therefore be that the working code goes through the freemarker servlet and the other does not. I am trying to find out at the moment whether the freemarkerservlet does something that I do not do when adding objects. I don't understand why in one context it appears to work and in the other it does not ...

Comment: ddekany, you were right after all. I could have saved myself a lot of time if I had looked at the abstract class that the object extends. There is in fact a method called "public Id id(Object object) {". I didn't think for one minute that something in there could be of interest. Sorry for wasting time. And thanks again! I ended up putting the static object structure into the location where it didn't work and suddenly that worked. The only difference I could see then was that the interface and abstract class were missing compared to the original. After adding those the error appeared.

Comment: At least I have learnt a lot about freemarker during all this digging. I have never had a similar issue when using JSP. Is there a debugging option whereby freemarker looks for possible clashes and outputs them. That would be quite a handy feature in my opinion. I think this could be particularly useful for freemarker beginners, particularly as the error messages are IMHO not very straightforward at first.

Comment: Well, it's an unlucky naming clash. What would JSP EL do? And actually FreeMarker has told that it's a method, and that was exactly the problem. Sure, there was gibberish there like `SimpleMethodModel`... FreeMarker 2.3.20 error messages are better in that regard BTW. And no, there's no option that would show the anatomy of the data-model.

Comment: I just found this question after experiencing the same problem. Thanks, because your answer helped me figure out what to do, but the error message is exactly the same in 2.3.20 and still pretty unhelpful to the novice. It would be useful if the error message could give you the name of the method that it is wrapping, then you would know that it has picked up the wrong one.

To answer your question of "what would JSP EL do?"; EL only accesses bean properties and so would not have any visibility of the id() method, only getId().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so it can be marked as solved... the problem was that there was an inherited Java method called "id" (no "get" before it). Since FreeMarker doesn't use separate name-space for methods and other members (methods are first-class values in FreeMarker, so you can get them without calling them), this will be a name clash, and the "id" method had priority over the "id" JavaBean property. In such case you can still use `getId()` to read the JavaBean property.